# Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError

Tags: linux, java, oracle, jdk, weblogic

**Context:**

Trying to install Oracle WebLogic Infrastructure 12.2.1.4.0 on Oracle Linux 8.5. JDK 7 & JDK 8 are installed.

**Issue:**

[image: Error in the console when trying to run the .jar]

Comment: Please don't post images. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) for why not.

Comment: Please don't post images. See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) for why not.